# Sobre a palavra Líquido

Tags: significado, etimologia

Por que a palavra "Líquido" é usada tanto como algo livre de descontos ou tributos, como para designar algo que flui ou escorre?

Exemplo:

- O suco é um líquido gostoso!
- Seu salário líquido será de $ 1000.

Comment: Parece ser um sentido figurativo: aquilo que é líquido é o que flui – como a parte do dinheiro que de fato flui para o seu bolso, ou o conteúdo que flui de uma embalagem para fora (representado pelo "conteúdo líquido" no rótulo).

Comment: Excelente pergunta. Uma daquelas palavras que nós usamos com sentidos diferentes sem nos darmos conta (até que alguém se dá). E já há duas respostas diferentes (uma num comentário).

Comment: Note que "líquido" no sentido contábil/financeiro não significa "livre de descontos" mas "o resto após aplicar os descontos" exemplo: Salário bruto: R$ 1.200,00 | total de descontos R$ 200,00 | Salário Líquido: R$ 1.000,00

Comment: ao segundo: 6. [Economia]  Que não está sujeito a descontos ou encargos (ex.: salário líquido).
7. [Economia]  Que pode ser convertido em moeda.

"líquido", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2013, http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/l%C3%ADquido [consultado em 11-02-2016].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Líquido* significa também [*claro, transparente*](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/l%C3%ADquido), *puro* e daí [*perfeitamente determinado; apurado, ajustado; que não tem já deduções a experimentar*](http://www.aulete.com.br/l%C3%ADquido).

Repara ainda que o Wiktionary lista para [*liquidus*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/liquidus#Latin) também *unadulterated, unmixed, pure*.

Answer (score 1):

Vem de uma transferência a partir dos adjetivos bruto e líquido usados na pesagem de líquidos (por exemplo, vinho), em que o peso líquido é o peso somente do vinho enquanto o peso bruto considera também o peso do recipiente (que, no caso de barris de madeira, pode ser uma fração considerável do peso do líquido contido).  Como não se pode medir o vinho tirando-o do barril, mede-se o vinho com o barril, depois subtrai-se o peso do barril vazio.

Da mesma forma, o valor "líquido" é o valor que resta depois de subtrair-se, a partir do valor "bruto", os descontos devidos ("peso do recipiente").

Comment: A ideia da ligação entre quantia líquida e peso líquido é atrativa, mas tradicionalmente os líquido eram medidos em volume, não em peso. Eu cresci numa região vinhateira, e ninguém pesava vinho ou barris. Aliás se falasses lá em pesar vinho, as pessoas pensariam que estavas a falar em medir o teor alcoólico do mosto. O instrumento usado para isso é conhecido por *pesa*.